# Skip specific field name

Tags: mysql, php

I am trying to execute a table from a MySQL database using a `for` loop statement, in order to get the field names as the column header.

Here is my code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bom_commonmaterials where description like '%CAP%'");
        if (!$result) {
            die("Query to show fields from table failed");
        }

        $fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);

        echo "<table class ='tableinventory' id ='tabletoexcel'><thead><tr>";
        // printing table headers
        for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
        {
            $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
            echo "<th>{$field->name}</th>";
            if ($field ="WATTAGE")
            {
                CONTINUE;
            }
        }
        echo "</tr></thead>\n";
        // printing table rows
        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
        {
            echo "<tr>";

            // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
            // of $row to $cell variable
            foreach($row as $cell)
                echo "<td>$cell</td>";

            echo "</tr>\n";

        }
        mysql_free_result($result);
        echo "</table>";
```

As you can see, I have an if statement `$field ="WATTAGE"` inside the for loop statement. I am trying to execute this code so that the field name WATTAGE will be not included as a table header, but I think my code is wrong.

In this case I need help on how to skip a specific field name, and also the field rows of this field name.

*Note: I used loop statement in this because the table field name from the database is not fixed. For example the user wants to add new columns. So I can't just code it manually because the table doesn't have a fixed data.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have an IF ELSE in your `for` loop:

```
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
```

You are assigning `$field` to the string WATTAGE here:

```
$field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
echo "<th>{$field->name}</th>";
```

**before** you get to the code

```
echo "<th>{$field->name}</th>";
if ($field ="WATTAGE")
{
  CONTINUE;
}
```

WATTAGE has has already been assigned to `$field` before you get to `if($field = "WATTAGE")` code.

Put an IF/ELSE in your `for` loop and then put the `CONTINUE;` bit in the IF and the assignment in the ELSE part. That way you'll never get to the `$field` assignment if the fieldname is WATTAGE.

Comment: Then maybe you could mark my answer as correct? :-)